# Reading blob data using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, blob

I have an application where a user is allowed to save some text data into a MYSQL database through a web interface. In addition, they can also attach a file to this text and I save this into a blob field. The file types that get attached are simple .txt files.

I am able to save this data into the database but I am having trouble retrieving it. This is what I am doing to retrieve it right now:

```
//Events that take place when trying to retreive an attached file
function getFile(rowid){

    //Make an AJAX Request to fetch the file
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'point-of-contact.php',
        data: 'page=attachment&row='+rowid,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
                console.log (data);
        }
    });
}
```

The AJAX request above leads to the following PHP code:

```
$attachments = $poc -> getPOC($_GET['row']);
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $attachments;
```

The problem I face is that when I console log the data received from the AJAX request I get this:

[image]

How do I go about getting the data in simple text format?

Could it be that the way I am uploading the file to the database is incorrect? This is how the file is uploaded to the DB:

```
    //File upload code
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

    //Hide the save button
    $("#save-button-1").hide(); 

    //Make the AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'point-of-contact.php?page=add',
        data: 'point_of_contact=' + $("#textarea1").val() + '&point_of_contact_attachment=' + file,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#done-1').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#done-1').fadeOut();
            }, 2500);
                $('.loader').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not save the attachment in that big database of files (*your filesystem*) and store in MySQL the path at which it can be found?  You know, right tool for the right job etc.

Comment: also, you should sanetize `$_GET['row']`, so you don't end up getting a SQL injection.

Comment: @twall It is sanitized in my model.

Comment: Since you're calling it `application/octet-stream`, the browser can't know what it is. If it is plain text, send it as `text/plain`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I just tried that and I still get [object File]

Comment: @karancan Set the ajax call's property `dataType: "text"`  Also, instead of just console.log(), look in the Network tab and view the actual http response, to see if it is what you expect it to have been.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I changed the dataType to text and the network response is [object File]. Does this mean that there is a problem with the response?

Comment: Please, provide an example, so we can check it live. Also, check the really sent headers in Network pane

Comment: @SamuelHapak what are the headers I should be looking out for?

Comment: @karancan What about posting all of them here?

Comment: Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @SamuelHapak as well as a cookie header that was too long to post here

Comment: Does it work without using ajax?

Comment: @karancan Cookie header is not interesting now. The problem I see is, there is missing Content-type header. Please, check these things: 1.) You do not include any php file with `?>` end tag before `header()` directive nor you use `?>` this tag before it 2.) If you use utf-8 encoding, make sure you do not have BOM character at the beginning of file

Comment: Question edited showing the method used to upload the file to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem in your upload section. The line

```
var file = fileInput.files[0];
```

assignes file object into `file` variable. Later, when you add it to

```
"point_of_contact_attachment="
```

it gets converted to string. So you will have

"point_of_contact_attachment=[object file]"

And that is it.

Answer (score -1):

try pointing the browser directly to the file instead of using ajax.
Like this

```
document.location = point-of-contact.php?page=attachment&row='+rowid;
```

Since it is not a file the browser can read, it will just download it.

However you will still need to get the TXT via ajax, because document.location redirect to the user to a plain text page.

Comment: Still only getting [object File]

Comment: Try erasing 

    header('Content-type: text/plain');

Comment: Wait, thats weird, document.location shouldnt log anything I'm pretty sure you're still using ajax.

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference

Comment: It doesn't log it, it echoes it to the page

Comment: Oh... weird. Your best bet would probably be to use php to save the file to the filesystem and using mysql to store the location.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15825/discussion-between-julian-and-karancan)